# Python dataframes : select columns by name and by filter

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to select some columns by name, like

```
selection = df[['Name', 'Qualification']]
```

and some columns by a filter like

```
selection = df.filter(regex=("Level.*"))
```

How to combine those selections in one instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can list all of the column names you want (as in, the number isn't massive), you can do this:

```py
selection = df.filter(regex=("Level.*|Name|Qualification"))
```

The `|` character in the regex means `or`, so that line will take any column that matches one of:

- `"Level.*"`
- `"Name"`
- `"Qualification"`

Comment: Well, thanks! This is of course this obvious answer! I should be tired...

Answer (score 1):

Probably lots of ways to go but I would select them separately then use

```
pd.concat([selection1, selection2], axis=1)
```

Maybe some other ideas in the [merging docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: Thanks! It's good to keep this method on the side.  For this work, I'll simply keep the `filter` selection as proposed by @baileythegreen.